# A program supposed to write all correct parantheses in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm attempting to write a program that (For a given natural `n`, not greater than 50):

- Writes all possible combinations of `2n` parentheses that are correct, which means that at every line of the otput there's a sequence of parentheses with those properties:

  - The sequence has `n` open, `n` closed parentheses
  - At no point there is a closing parenthesis that was not opened

I've done almost exactly the same code in Java and it works perfectly, but somehow the following code breaks:

```
MAX = 100;
arr = [];
for i in range(0, MAX):
        arr.append(' ');

def write(n, pos, op, cl):
        if (cl == n):
                for i in range(0, MAX):
                        if arr[i] != ' ':
                                print(arr[i]);
                        else:
                                break;
                print("\n");
        else:
                if (op > cl):
                        arr[pos] = ')';
                        write(n, pos+1, op, cl+1);
                if (op < n):
                        arr[pos] = '(';
                        write(n, pos+1, op+1, cl);

n = raw_input();

write(n, 0, 0, 0);
```

The idea is pretty basic, but when I'm trying to run it, I get an error stating that at some point the statement

```
arr[pos] = '(';
```

Is illegal since the variable `pos` is `>= MAX`

I'm not very acquainted with Python yet, but I can't see the reason from the algorithmic point of view.

I'd appreciate any ideas

Comment: your code works without errors for me. i tried `write(4, 0, 0, 0);` and `write(14, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Well, it seems that if I call the function without getting n by raw_input, the code works. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: for 100 parenthesis (`2n=100`, `n=50`) there are [1978261657756160653623774456](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50th+catalan+number) possible [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics). Are you really trying to print all of them?

Comment: `raw_input` is a string. How about `n = int(n)`

Comment: raw_input returns string. use input() instead, to get an integer. it works this way, just tried it.
note: in python3, there is only input()

Comment: @mata actually I'm doing the program to see the difference in speed between Python and Java, so input like 50 will probably lead to stack overflow. But it's quite interesting for inputs like 12. Hence the ridiculous code ;)

Comment: @kecer, no don't do that, cast to an int.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: why? both throw errors when given invalid input (NameError vs ValueError)

Comment: @kecer because `eval(raw_input())` can lead to very bad things

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OH IT EVALS, I had no idea! Thank god I have switched to p3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Python 2.7.9, but basically your problem is that you're using [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), which gets input in the form of a string.

If you just convert that to an integer using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), your code will work:

```
MAX = 100;
arr = [];
for i in range(0, MAX):
        arr.append(' ')

def write(n, pos, op, cl):
        if (cl == n):
                for i in range(0, MAX):
                        if arr[i] != ' ':
                                print(arr[i]), #add a comma here
                        else:
                                break;
                print("\n")
        else:
                if (op > cl):
                        arr[pos] = ')'
                        write(n, pos+1, op, cl+1)
                if (op < n):
                        arr[pos] = '('
                        write(n, pos+1, op+1, cl)

n = int(raw_input())  #change the input to an integer

write(n, 0, 0, 0)
```

Also, I added a comma after your print statement, so it would output like this:

```
>>> 
3
( ) ( ) ( ) 

( ) ( ( ) ) 

( ( ) ) ( ) 

( ( ) ( ) ) 

( ( ( ) ) )
```